# Simple htaccess redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to create a redirection like this:

```
   http://www.myserver.com/recipe/xxxxx.html?v1=blabla&fb_action_ids=bla&v3=blablabla
```

To

`http://www.myserver.com/recipe/xxxx.html`

Note: xxxx in the url is different according to the page.

htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^home.htm http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^breads.htm http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/whatwemake/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cakes.htm http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/patisserie/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^farmers_market.htm http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/wheretobuy/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about_us.htm http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/ourstory/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contacts.htm http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/contact/ [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(recipe/[^.]+\.html)\?fb_action_ids=[^\s]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(news/[^.]+\.html)\?fb_action_ids=[^\s]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(event/[^.]+\.html)\?fb_action_ids=[^\s]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+((?:news|event|recipe)/[^.]+\.html)\?fb_action_ids=[^\s]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: whats this doing `[A-Z]{3,}\s/+`

Comment: +1 for your help, however, I'm still having no redirection. Let me upload my htacces

Comment: @DevZer0: `[A-Z]{3,}\s/+` matches something like `GET /` OR `GET ///`

Comment: @Romain: .htaccess looks fine, What URL did you try to test it?

Comment: oh i see so `THE_REQUEST` is the actual request it self. interesting. Thanks

Comment: Here is an example of a redirection: 

http://www.xxxxxwrrwrwrxxx.co.uk/news/opening-our-first-bakery-cafe-in-tunbridge-wells.html?fb_action_ids=355353535353&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=355353355353

Comment: Your test URL doesn't have `/recipe/` and it also doesn't have `?v1=...` so of course it wont match the rule.

Comment: Let me say it properly, I would like to remove all the fb variable to the url for the news|event and recipe section.
here is an example of a back link from facebook: http://www.website.co.uk/recipe/spiced-apple,-sultana-&-almond-tart.html?fb_action_ids=10151533719284958&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582

Comment: Alright modified the code as per your latest comment. Try it now.

Comment: You don't need 3 separate rules. Also make sure it is in $DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess

Comment: Sorry I'm not really use to modify htaccess file. My htaccess file is available at this path: httpdocs/public/.htaccess
But my other redirections are working.
Also, if I don't need 3 different rule how can I apply the redirection to my three different folders?

Comment: @Romain: Check my answer above on how to handle 3 different paths in URI.

Answer (score 1):

This thing is via `GET` method `[?v1=blabla&v2=bla&v3=blablabla]` use `POST` then

Comment: I don't want to get any variables, I just want to redirect the user.

Comment: This are external links linked to my website.
Some times, people are adding variables to the links and I'm displaying the error page.

Comment: I would like to redirect them to my page without taking any information

Answer (score 1):

You need a simple rewrite rule

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*).html(.*) $1.html
```

Comment: Tried it, but the redirection isn't done, here is an link example: http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/recipe/spiced-apple,-sultana-&-almond-tart.html?fb_action_ids=452245&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=244242425425425 +1 for your help

Comment: `AllowOverride All` needs to be set on the directory that has the .htaccess file or a parent of it.